# javascript add child and parent elements

Tags: javascript

How to create dynamic image drawing, my javascript **foreach** element commands:

```
temp = document.getElementById(docElement);
temp.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
temp.lastElementChild.innerText = 'text';
temp.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
```

**docElement** is simple another div container
it draws:

```
<div id="docElement">
<div>text</div>
<img></img>
<div>text</div>
<img></img>
<div>text</div>
<img></img>
...
</div>
```

I wanted:

```
<div id="docElement">
<div>text<img></img></div>
<div>text<img></img></div>
<div>text<img></img></div>
<div>text<img></img></div>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting in out of the inside div coz you are appending the image to main div `docElement`. Simply store them in different variable and play with them whatever way you want like this

```js
temp = document.getElementById("docElement");
innerdiv = document.createElement('div');
temp.appendChild(innerdiv);
innerdiv.innerText = 'text';
innerdiv.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
```

```html
<div id="docElement">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = document.getElementById(docElement);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = 'text';
div.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));     
temp.appendChild(div);
```